# How to use GA solver tool

Tags: matlab

I want to calibrate a model using GA solver tool, and the model equation is given below

```
Acal = α((Vo (tan h(γ*(x – xc)) + tan h(γ *xc))) – v)
```

and my objective function is

```
y = minimize(sum(Aobs-Acal)^2)
```

I have a sheet of data. I tried with the code below but I am not getting the results what I expected. Can any one tell whether GA can solve equation with hyperbolic function?

```
function[y] = gaobj(x)

g1 = xlsread('C:\Users\ANUSREE\Desktop\ovmpairs.xlsx');
i = 1;
for i = 1:22494
    x(i) = (g1(i, 8) - (x(1) * (x(2) * (tanh(x(3) * (g1(i, 7) - x(4)) + tanh(x(3) * x(4)))) - g1(i, 6))))^2; % this is == (Aobs-Acal)^2 
    i = i + 1;
end
y = sum(x);

end
```

Comment: why would it not be correct? Have you tried it?

Comment: Note that your increment of `i` in the inner for loop is useless. The for loop with automatically increment `i` (and override it).

Comment: Yes, I tried but the result is not what I expected. So I am afraid whether GA can solve equation with Hyperbolic function or not.

Comment: OP, put that information into the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Not related to your question, but do not use `i` as a variable, as it is used by MATLAB for the unit imaginary number and you would overwrite it.